# Can someone please show the steps from the question to the answer?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I have a question which has an answer without steps in between.

Can someone help?

$$m(t)=E\left(e^{tY}\right) = \sum_{y=0}^n \binom{n}{y}\left(pe^t\right)^yq^{n-y} = \left(pe^t+q\right)^n$$

To not cause confusion, m(x) is the moment-generating function for a binomial distribution.

Thank you!

Comment: The last equality is just the binoniam theorem $$(a+b)^n = \sum_{y=0}^n \binom n y a^yb^{n-y}$$ for $a=pe^t$ and $b=q$. The first equality is just the definition of the moment generating function for any random variable $Y$. All that's left is the middle equality.

Comment: Oh my God, I never think that is the binomial theorem...Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equality is just the definition of the moment generating function for a random variable $Y$. The last inequality is just the binomial theorem:

$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{y=0}^n \binom n y a^yb^{n-y}$$

with $a=pe^{t}$ and $b=q$.

So the last is the middle equality. We have:

$$E(e^{tY}) = \sum_{y} P(Y=y) e^{ty}$$ 
With $Y$ a binomial distribution, $y$ can take any integer value from $0$ to $n$ with:

$$P(Y=y) = \binom{n}{y}p^yq^{n-y}$$ So:

$$E(e^{tY}) = \sum_{y=0}^n \binom n yp^yq^{n-y}e^{yy} = \sum_{y=0}^n \binom n y(pe^t)^yq^{n-y}$$

Another approach to prove the same theorem is the following. If $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots,X_n$ are independent random variables then:

$$E\left(e^{t(X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n)}\right) = E\left(e^{tX_1}\right)E\left(e^{tX_2}\right)\cdots E\left(e^{tX_n}\right)\tag{*}$$

Then our $Y=Y_1+Y_2+\dots+Y_n$ where the $Y_i$ are independent the random variables equal to $0$ with probability $q$ and $1$ with probability $p$. So if you know $(*)$ then you only need to compute $E(e^{tY_1}) = qe^0 + pe^{t}$.

Proving $(*)$ is, however, not any easier than the first proof. It only has the advantage of being more general, and it gives you an idea of what is going on more generally.